# beamer: Different numbering for Theorems, Examples, Definition, and Lemma

Tags: beamer, numbering, theorems

I want to have different numbering for Theorems, Examples, Definition, and Lemma. I use the following code in preamble

```
\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
```

This code works fine but it has continuing numbering for Theorems and other Environments. I'd appreciate your help if you guide me how to get different numbering for Theorems, Examples, Definition, and Lemma in `beamer`.

Comment: BTW, numbering *anything* in a presentation is most probably a very bad idea.  Unless the presentation is for the speaker (to put one more item in the cv, for example) and not for the audience, of course (as is often the case).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Load `beamer` with the `notheorems` option and declare all theorem types "by hand" without introducing a common numbering scheme. (Note: This is somewhat a hack, as it breaks the `countsect` package option [theorem numbering by section] for every type but `theorem`.)

```
\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorem}[ams style]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\makeatletter
    \ifbeamer@countsect
      \newtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}[section]
    \else
      \newtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}
    \fi
    \newtheorem{corollary}{\translate{Corollary}}
    \newtheorem{fact}{\translate{Fact}}
    \newtheorem{lemma}{\translate{Lemma}}
    \newtheorem{problem}{\translate{Problem}}
    \newtheorem{solution}{\translate{Solution}}

    \theoremstyle{definition}
    \newtheorem{definition}{\translate{Definition}}
    \newtheorem{definitions}{\translate{Definitions}}

    \theoremstyle{example}
    \newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}
    \newtheorem{examples}{\translate{Examples}}


    % Compatibility
    \newtheorem{Beispiel}{Beispiel}
    \newtheorem{Beispiele}{Beispiele}
    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \newtheorem{Loesung}{L\"osung}
    \newtheorem{Satz}{Satz}
    \newtheorem{Folgerung}{Folgerung}
    \newtheorem{Fakt}{Fakt}
    \newenvironment{Beweis}{\begin{proof}[Beweis.]}{\end{proof}}
    \newenvironment{Lemma}{\begin{lemma}}{\end{lemma}}
    \newenvironment{Proof}{\begin{proof}}{\end{proof}}
    \newenvironment{Theorem}{\begin{theorem}}{\end{theorem}}
    \newenvironment{Problem}{\begin{problem}}{\end{problem}}
    \newenvironment{Corollary}{\begin{corollary}}{\end{corollary}}
    \newenvironment{Example}{\begin{example}}{\end{example}}
    \newenvironment{Examples}{\begin{examples}}{\end{examples}}
    \newenvironment{Definition}{\begin{definition}}{\end{definition}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{theorem}[A theorem]
Some text.
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}[A definition]
Some text.
\end{definition}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @lockstep for your nice answer. Much appreciated your time and effort.

Comment: Very thank you!